# Launch new activity with spinner using Submit button

Tags: android, button, spinner

I have a spinner that launches the activity when it is selected automatically. How would I have a Submit button so that the user can first select which activity they'd like to launch, and then tap Submit to go to the selected screen? Here's what I currently have:

```
 private Spinner spinner;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("TEST", "this is a test");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.entries,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new function());

}


public class function implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos,
            long id) {
        String selection = ((TextView)arg1).getText().toString();
        if (selection.equals("Red Screen")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(arg1.getContext(), DisplayMessageActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if(selection.equals("Math Screen")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(arg1.getContext(), Numbers.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(arg1.getContext(), Face.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Java has naming convention. Please rename clase from `function` to `Function`

Comment: @user902691 Function isn't even a very descriptive class name, not to mention misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 private Class activityToOpen;

 private Spinner spinner;
 private Button button;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
     button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

     ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.entries,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
     spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new function());
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
                    if(activityToOpen!=null)
                    {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), activityToOpen);
                    startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}

public class function implements OnItemSelectedListener {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos,
        long id) {
    String selection = ((TextView)arg1).getText().toString();
    if (selection.equals("Red Screen")){
        activityToOpen = DisplayMessageActivity.class;
    }else if(selection.equals("Math Screen")){
        activityToOpen = Numbers.class;
    }else{
        activityToOpen = Face.class;
    }
```

Comment: Ah, making the activityToOpen as a class was what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its simple `oncreate` `Disable` the button

And in `OnItemSelectedListener` if the option is selected enable the button. Hence you are forcing the user to select any option from the list (spinner)

Comment: I'm new to Android - depending on which screen is selected on the spinner, pushing the button will do something different. How do I update the action of pushing the button depending on what is selected in the spinner?

Comment: @mcon Let me first understand a) You dont want user to press submit button until he has selected anything from the spinner correct??

Answer (score 0):

In your `OnClickListener`, you should read the selection of the `Spinner` and start the appropriate activity. You should look at the [Android Training Tutorials](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) and the [Android API Guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html) for information about how to do this. After consoluting these documents, feel free to come back with specific questions when you get stuck.